# Secure Websocket connections with OAuth in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, websocket, oauth

I am going to add a WebSocket handler to my Spring Boot 3 application. But along with that, I want to secure it with OAuth. There is an already prepared authorization server for that. **The important thing** is that I want to use pure WebSocket instead of STOMP, so I will use `@EnableWebSocket` instead of `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` because I don't need all that complexity and functionality that broker-backed messaging over WebSocket introduces.

**The questions is:** How can OAuth validation be implemented in this case? Should I implement an interceptor? Should I perform the validation during handhsake? Looks like `@EnableWebSocketSecurity` is not suitable for this case, since it's acceptable when you use broker-backed messaging over WebSocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple but requires some explanations, so I had to write a small article about that. I will attach the link at the end. Here, I will try to explain in short.

##### First important thing

If we are using pure WebSocket connections, there is a handshake process that is performed before a WebSocket connection is set up. The handshake is performed using HTTP/HTTPS (depending on your settings). After the handshake is performed, the connection is switched to WebSocket.

##### Second important thing

Since the handshake is performed using HTTP/HTTPS, we can cover the security needs with the usual security configuration that we use to secure endpoints. Security changes will be executed during the handshake. If the security validation is not passed, the handshake will fail and the WebSocket connection will not be set up.

##### Necessary dependencies

Except for the WebSocket dependency, we need only the usual security dependency and the dependency to connect to the OAuth authorization server:

```
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
 implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
```

##### Configuration

In the configuration, we just set up OAuth server validation and describe security rules for the desired endpoint.

```java
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(registry -> registry
                        .requestMatchers("/websocket/endpoint").hasAuthority("SCOPE_my.scope")
                )
                .oauth2ResourceServer(configurer -> configurer
                        .jwt(withDefaults())
                )
                .build();
    }

}
```

##### OAuth properties

In the application properties file we need to set up properties for our connections to the authorization server. In my case the server is located on `http://auth-server:9000`.

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: http://auth-server:9000
```

And that's it. Now, during the handshake, the described security rules will be applied. The described application properties will be used during the connection to the authorization server. When the handshake is performed, the WebSocket connection will be set up.

##### Full article

Link to the article (step-by-step guide): https://medium.com/@HereAndBeyond/bf479327339f